# Telerik RadGrid: how do I add a new row from code behind?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

What's the simplest way to add a new row to a Telerik RadGrid in ASP.NET from code behind?

Comment: How is the grid databound to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a new item in the grid source and rebind the grid, this should do the trick (since the Telerik grid is data-bound control). To display the insertion form, set the MasterTableView.IsItemInserted property to true.

Dick

Comment: Thanks, there is no way to add the row without rebind?

Answer (score 1):

The basics of adding a row are described in [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/alleditablecolumns/defaultcs.aspx) from Telerik's website. Generally though, through the code behind, there are a few method that I've found that you need to make a telerik grid work:

- RadGrid1_NeedDataSource - used for paging and on_load events
- RadGrid1_UpdateCommand - updating a row
- RadGrid1_ItemDataBound - bindingto a row item
- RadGrid1_RemoveCommand - removing a row item

  GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;

Wil give you access to a row item. And:

```
editedItem.GetDataKeyValue()
```

will give you access to an id associted with each row item.

Good luck, and hope this helps out some.